# Can CO2 be cracked by electrolysis?

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, bond, elements

What can be added to liquid $\ce{CO2}$ to lower the electricity needed to crack $CO_2$ ? Answer: Zirconium dioxide

What form and temperature of $\ce{CO2}$ is best to crack with or without Zirconium dioxide?

https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/19755/can-carbon-dioxide-be-broken-down-by-electrolysis

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, none of those sentences make any sort of chemical or electrochemical sense to me. Baking soda doesn't break water down in any manner I'm aware of. What do you mean by "break CO2 down?" Electrolysis requires an electrolyte; there do exist solid electrolytes, but they are always ionic compounds, not covalent ones like CO2, so no, electrolysis will not work in solid CO2. Neon gas will not carry electric current at all, unless you apply such a high voltage that you ionize it into plasma.

Comment: I'm pretty sure @hBy2Py adequately answered this, so it can't possibly be unclear.

Comment: @M.A.R. Especially after looking at the linked question on SX.SE, I think there's an answerable question lurking in there somewhere -- I just for the life of me can't figure out what it is. Muze, you might want to head to the [Chem.SE main chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3229/the-periodic-table) to get some help clarifying what you're looking for, and then edit the question accordingly.

Comment: @hBy I think it's the one in the title.

Comment: @Muze Ok, so ... are you assuming you've got the CO2 pressurized and cooled such that it's a liquid?

Comment: You mean like electrolysis of water?  A major difference is water's polarity which makes it electrolysable, and also liquid and a good solvent of ionic compounds as well.

Comment: @JosephHirsch my [feeble attempt at remembering chemistry](http://space.stackexchange.com/a/19756/12102) has something to do with the appearance of this question. While electrolysis of gaseous CO2 at high temperature is workable - [see MOXIE](http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/5094/how-do-you-make-oxygen-on-mars/5096#5096) - Muze is (seems to be) asking (roughly) if electrolysis of liquid CO2 is possible, and if something can be added to the liquid to enhance its bulk electrical conductivity. This is not to suggest it would be a good or practical way to to it. Thanks for your help!